# How to find variations of a word from source code (python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.6

I have to write a program that takes user input for a website and keyword, and then reads the source code of the website for that word. I have to code it so it detects many variations of the word (ex. hello vs. hello, vs. hello!) and am not sure how to do this. I have it coded like this so far to detect the exact input, but I'm not sure how to get multiple variations. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

```
def main():
    [n,l]=user()
    print("Okay", n, "from", l, ", let's get started.")

    webname=input("What is the name of the website you wish to browse? ")
    website=requests.get(input("Please enter the URL: "))
    txt = website.text

    list=txt.split(",")
    print(type(txt))
    print(type(list))
    print(list[0:10])

    while True:
        numkey=input("Would you like to enter a keyword? Please enter yes or no: ")

        if numkey=="yes":
            key=input("Please enter the keyword to find: ")

        else:
            newurl()
        break

        find(webname,txt,key)

def find(web,txt,key):
    findtext=txt
    list=findtext.split(sep=" ")

    count = 0
    for item in list:
        if item==key:
            count=count+1
    print("The word", key, "appears", count, "times on", web)

def newurl():
    while True:
        new=input("Would you like to browse another website? Please enter yes or no: ")

        if new=="yes":
            main()

        else:
            [w,r]=experience()
            return new
        break

def user():
    name=input("Hello, what is your name? ")
    loc=input("Where are you from? ")
    return [name,loc]

def experience():

    wordeval=input("Please enter 3 words to describe the experience, separated by spaces (ex. fun cool interesting): ") 
    list=wordeval.split(sep=" ")

    rate=eval(input("Please rate your experience from 1-10: "))

    if rate < 6:
        print("We're sorry you had a negative", list[0], "and", list[2], "experience!")

    else: 
        print("Okay, thanks for participating. We're glad your experience was", list[1], "!")

    return[wordeval,rate]

main()
```

Comment: What are the "multiple variations"?  Please define that, and provide a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: In find(), being able to distinguish "hello" as a keyword in source code in many forms, for example "hello!" or "hello,". Right now it can only detect the word in the exact syntax. Sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the re module.  You can get indices of the matches, individual match instances, etc.  There are some good tutorials [here](https://pymotw.com/2/re/) that you can look at for how to use the module, but looping through the html source code line by line and looking for matches is easy enough, or you can find the indices within the string itself (if you've split it by newline, or just left it as one long text string).